# Good way to get Eigen matrix element type

Tags: c++, types, eigen

I am writing a simple interface between `std::vector` and *Eigen* for my project. For a simple matrix-matrix multiplication code:

```
template<typename MatrixElementType1, typename MatrixElementType2>
    inline auto _matmat( const vector<MatrixElementType1>& Mat1, 
                         const vector<MatrixElementType2>& Mat2,
                         const size_t M, const size_t N, const size_t K)
    {
        using MatrixType1 = Matrix<MatrixElementType1, Dynamic, Dynamic>;
        using MatrixType2 = Matrix<MatrixElementType2, Dynamic, Dynamic>;
        Map<const MatrixType1> m1(Mat1.data(), M, N); 
        Map<const MatrixType2> m2(Mat2.data(), N, K); 
        auto rst = m1 * m2; 
        return vector<???>(rst.data(), rst.data() + rst.size());

    }
```

The questions is what should I use for ??? .. I know `decltype(rst(0,0))` works, but is there a more elegent way? It seems `decltype(rst)::value_type` does not work for *Eigen* Matrix..

Comment: Using `auto` near expression templates? You like living dangerously...

Comment: It will be perfect if I can decide which type to use simply based on `MatrixElementType1` and `MatrixElementType2`.. but I'm not sure how to do that

Comment: It turns out I have to perform a cast before multiplying matrices if `MatrixElementType1` does not equal to `MatrixElementType2`, but the question is still there: should I cast `Mat1` to `MatrixElementType2` or should I cast `Mat2` to `MatrixElementType1` ?..

Answer (score 1):

First of all, since `m1*m2` returns an expression and not the result of the product, you need to evaluate it explicitly if using auto:

```
auto rst = (m1 * m2).eval();
```

Then, you can get the scalar type with `decltype(rst)::Scalar`. A better strategy though might be to declare a std::vector of appropriate type and size, and map it:

```
typedef decltype(m1*m2)::Scalar ResScalar;
vector<ResScalar> res(M,K);
Matrix<ResScalar,Dynamic,Dynamic>::Map(res.data(),M,K).noalias() = m1*m2;
return res;
```

Comment: Didn't realize there exists `Scalar`, thanks. Although better than my version, this will still not work if two types are `double` and `int`, because I have to _cast_ before I call `m1 * m2` (otherwise eigen will throw a long error...). What I currently do is to deduct `ResType` by `decltype(static_cast<MatrixElementType1>(1) *                                    static_cast<MatrixElementType2>(1));` then map it following the code above...